# Python Chrome Selenium clicking on hidden icon

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

Using python selenium (chromedriver) I am trying to click on a section of an element and can't seem to figure out how to do this.  In the image below, how would I click on the "gear" icon?

[image]

Comment: Locate the element and use `click()` method.

Comment: Have you tried using the developer tools in your browser to determine the element name/id/etc.?

Answer (score 0):

As per provided image, i am expecting that, that gear image will be displayed as soon as moving mouse to Time.  So first move mouse then click there..

in Java

```
 Actions move=new Actions(driver);
  move.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("pathToTime"))).click(driver.findElement(By.xpath("pathToGear"))).build().perform();
```

Thank You,
Murali

Answer (score 0):

First get the element using method 'find_element_by_xpath' and then perform click operation on the returned object. Below is the sample code that will help you.

**CODE**

```
import time
...

elem = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//xpath/to/your/button/gear')
elem.click()
time.sleep(5) # for development purposes to make sure that click has successfully performed
```

The above script will perform a click on the button/tag.